# How to replace the shell application with my own through c# code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

after deep looking I still can't find a solution to my problem. My goal is to change the shell (explorer.exe) with my own application , and this should be done on each computer the application is run automatically , which means that I will need some snippet of code in my application's constructor to do this. What I know for now is how to do it manually (through the Group Policy) but I need some C# code that will do it programatically , I suppose some way of managing the Group policy ... any help will be appreciated !

Comment: The shell started when a user logs in is a registry setting I believe.

Comment: Not leaving a comment about why you choose to downvote is lazy and non-constructive.

Comment: Agree with spender, it seems a reasonable specific question which has an answer, isn't that what this site is about.

Comment: AndyC , I found a manual way through Group policy , but I will be very grateful to any solution which I can implement , so if there is a registry setting for this , and it can be set through code I will mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the registry key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon\Shell

Comment: meziantou my question was for the exact code , but actually this is what I've already done so I take your answer for the correct one. If someone is interested in the solution : RegistryKey class is the answer.